# Set expiry time for laravel jwt dynamically

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, jwt

Hi I am using angular js in front end with satellizer and laravel at backend with tymon jwt library. I am using jwt authentication. I want to make remember me functionalities in my web app. I see 'ttl' to set expiry time of token in laravel 'config/jwt.php.

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT time to live
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify the length of time (in minutes) that the token will be valid for.
| Defaults to 1 hour
|
*/

'ttl' => 60,
```

By default, it will be 1 hour. But I want to change this dynamically to 1 week if user clicks remember me while login. How can I change it dynamically. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

You can add `exp` as a custom claim as follows:

```
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, ['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->timestamp]);
```

The code above creates a token that expires in 7 days time. You don't have to use `Carbon` it just requires a Unix timestamp, I've used `Carbon` here for simplicity since its built into Laravel.

Comment: @user254153 Did it work out for you? Would you mind accepting an answer to help out the community? Thanks.

Comment: Great solution! And how to set the ttl in jwt.php? Can I ignore the value then? However, could give the longest time I need... I that correct?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `JWTFactory` (1.0 version)

```
$myTTL = 30; //minutes

JWTAuth::factory()->setTTL($myTTL);
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do following to generate JWT token with needed expire time:

```
JWTAuth::customClaims(['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(2)->timestamp])
    ->fromUser($user);
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not 100% sure, but what happens if you set within your `AppServiceProvider@register` the config:

```
config()->set('jwt.ttl', 60*60*7);
```

or with a facade:

```
Config::set('jwt.ttl', 60*60*7);
```

Why would you set it dynamically? Or do you not use the publishing from the config (it's not publishing the `config/jwt.php`)?

**EDIT:**

Another solution would be to set it through your `.env` file:

```
config/jwt.php
// set the default TTL to one week if the .env file does not contain a `JWT_TTL` var
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60*60*7),
```

And within `.env`:

```
JWT_TTL=3600
```

Comment: Why would you set it dynamically? I already mentioned in question that. I want token to expire in 1 week only if user clicks remember me when login in to the system. If user logs in without remember me clicked then It should be 1 hr by default.

Comment: @user254153 Same situation here! How did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Tymon JWT v 1.0

you can override default ttl when attempting to login user:

```
if (! $token = auth()->setTTL(1)->attempt($credentials)) {
  return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized user'], 401);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me. I managed to get it working like this.

```
$ttl_in_minutes = 60*24*100;
// The parameter passed to the auth helper should match what is present in config/auth.php
if($request->input('remember')) auth('api')->factory()->setTTL($ttl_in_minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the token ttl without any changing in config/jwt.php

$token = auth()->setTTL(7200)->attempt($credentials);

Answer (score 0):

We can set token expiry time while creating the JWT token . It can be set in the token parameter. For example

```
$token      = array(
                         "iss" => "http://example.com",
                          "aud" => "http://example.com",
                          "exp" => {YOUR_EXPIRY_TIME}
                        );
$jwt=new JWT();
$JWT_TOKEN=$jwt->encode($token, {YOUR_KEY});
```

The new token will be generated with the corresponding expiry time.

Comment: How can I do in laravel end.

Answer (score 0):

For JWT version 1.0.0-rc.2 it's very clear described on the documentation on config/jwt.php

As per note :
....
*You can also **set this to null**, to yield a **never expiring token**.
Some people may want this behaviour for e.g. a mobile app.
This is not particularly recommended, so make sure you have appropriate
systems in place to revoke the token if necessary.
**Notice:** If you set this to null you should **remove 'exp' element** from 'required_claims' list.*

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60)  meaning we must set 60 to null

 'required_claims' => [
        'iss',
        'iat',
       // 'exp',  <- remove this
        'nbf',
        'sub',
        'jti',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the token expiration dynamically by using

```
JWTAuth::factory()->setTTL($expirationInMinutes);

JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)
```

Below code will not work in the latest version

```
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, ['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->timestamp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do that

```
$token = auth('api')->setTTL((AuthController::EXPIRE_IN_DAYS * AuthController::MINUTES_IN_DAY))->attempt($credentials);
```

get data payload

```
$data = JWTAuth::decode(new Token( $token))->toArray();
```

```
{
  "iss": "",
  "iat": ,
  "exp": ,
  "nbf": ,
  "jti": "",
  "sub": ,
  "prv": ""
}
```

```
response("Success",'LOGIN_SUCCESS',[
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => $data['exp']
        ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

## Increase Laravel auth token expire time

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=10080
```

Default value 120 min in session.php